# Need help in saving results in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am able to view individual stock data but not sure how to save data to the MktSmithData.csv file using loops.

Also, i am using two df frame variables, not sure if it is the best method and i presume there is a better way to do what i am doing.

Need to save Stock, GR, EPR, Fund values in a csv file. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

---

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 25 13:43:22 2023

@author: eruku
"""

import pandas as pd
import requests

infile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/StocksList.txt'
outfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/MktSmithData.csv'

timeout = 10
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

starturl = 'https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/0/3023210/symboldetails.json?s=20180719&e=20230719&text='
endurl = '&lang=en&isConsolidated=0&ms-auth=3990+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+0+230325200706+-514613229'
# stock = 'TCS'


with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT:
    for stock in IN:
        stock = stock.strip()
        url = starturl + stock + endurl
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        try:
            # line = '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (
            #     stock,
                
            # )
            df1 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsInternational']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsOrigin'][0])
            # df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
            df2 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
            GR = df2.loc[:,"industryGroupRank"]
            EPR = df2.loc[:,"epsRank"]
            Funds = df1.loc[:,"noOfFunds"]
            df1.to_csv('MktSmithData.csv', index=False)
        
            # print(line, file=OUT)
        except KeyError as E:
            print(stock, 'KeyError:', E)
        
# print(df)
print(GR)
print(EPR)
print(Funds)
```

Comment: Not sure I fully get your question. Are you getting an error trying to save the csv? also, on your last 3 lines, what you're really printing is the value of those variables on the last iteration - not sure if that's the intended behaviour

Comment: I am printing values, but not sure how to save those values into CSV. So i reached out.

Comment: You want to save the values you're printing into CSV? You've used the to_csv function once in your code already, it should be the same for any pandas dataframe

Comment: The structure of the 4 dataframes differs. Are you somehow trying to figure out how to combine them into one output CSV or 4 separate files?

Comment: Combine all output into one CSV file only

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly
We can build each row to a list as you find the value in your for loop and append it to another list.
Then we can write the list of lists using csv module to a csv file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 25 13:43:22 2023

@author: eruku
"""

import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

infile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/StocksList.txt'
outfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/MktSmithData.csv'

timeout = 10
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

starturl = 'https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/0/3023210/symboldetails.json?s=20180719&e=20230719&text='
endurl = '&lang=en&isConsolidated=0&ms-auth=3990+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+0+230325200706+-514613229'
# stock = 'TCS'

csvdata = []
with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT:
    for stock in IN:
        stock = stock.strip()
        url = starturl + stock + endurl
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)        
        try:
            # line = '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (
            #     stock,

            # )
            df1 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()[
                                    'response']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsInternational']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsOrigin'][0])
            # df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
            df2 = pd.json_normalize(
                r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
            GR = df2.loc[:, "industryGroupRank"]
            EPR = df2.loc[:, "epsRank"]
            Funds = df1.loc[:, "noOfFunds"]
            df1.to_csv('MktSmithData.csv', index=False)
            row = [GR, EPR, Funds]
            csvdata.append(row)
            # print(line, file=OUT)
        except KeyError as E:
            print(stock, 'KeyError:', E)

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(csvdata)

# print(df)
print(GR)
print(EPR)
print(Funds)
```